# How to call functions in a DLL that is currently load in another process?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

My question is the same as this one:
[Calling functions in a DLL loaded by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631357/calling-functions-in-a-dll-loaded-by-another-process)

I'm trying to call the `Test` function that is currently on a DLL load in a different process.

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    OutputDebugStringW(L"Loading Library...");
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LPCWSTR Test()
{
    DWORD pid= GetCurrentProcessId();

    WCHAR buf[255];
    wsprintf(buf, L"Current PID: %d", pid);
    OutputDebugString(buf);

    return std::to_wstring(pid).c_str();
}
```

I already learned how to do an IPC mechanism using `SendMessage` and a window that can handle the messages received.

I'm trying to understand the other options described in that post, like `CreateRemoteThread` or `named pipe`.
Would like to ask if someone could share a working example for this use case.

Comment: You can't *call* a function across process boundaries.  You would have to post a message to a window in the target process, and then have the message handler call the function. Or else *inject* code into the target process and have that code call the function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "Or else inject code into the target process and have that code call the function" how is this method called to i search more about.

Comment: Remote injection? There are numerous questions on StackOverflow related to using `CreateRemoteThread()` to inject a DLL into a process. Here is a simple tutorial: [Using CreateRemoteThread for DLL injection on Windows](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/). There are many ways to inject code, see [Ten process injection techniques: A technical survey of common and trending process injection techniques](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ten-process-injection-techniques-technical-survey-common-and-trending-process).